# IF statements and columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

really need your help

I have a series of values and blanks randomly distributed in one column and  I want to set up a formula in the next column which looks at the first column and says, if there is a value in first column then take that value, otherwise if there is a blank then use the last cell in which a number occurred.

But where it gets a bit complicated is - I want the formula to update the value which it uses from the first column every time a new number occurs in that column, meaning that as the first column encounters a new value after a series of blanks, the formula will discard the old or previous value and take the new one

To give an idea of what I mean, column B's formula must display the last value from column A even when it encounters blanks in column A until it encounters a new value in column A at which point it must update its output to that new encountered value from column A

[image]

Not sure if this is even possible but I will be really grateful if some kind person could help me with this, please

Thank you
Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, your "complication" isn't really one.  Formulas update when anything changes.  I think what your asking for is this:

[image]

The formula in J21 is:

```
=IF(I21="",J20,I21)
```

This just uses the previous value in column J if the cell in column I is blank.  Otherwise it uses the cell in column I.

This assumes that the formula starts where there is actually a value in column I, or it will grab the column title.  If that's a potential issue, you probably want blanks in column J until you hit a value in column I since there would be no previous value to reference. You could do that by nesting another IF test:

```
=IF(I21="",IF(OR(ROW()=21,J20=""),"",J20),I21)
```

You need to also test the previous J value for blank because telling Excel to put in the same value as a blank cell will display a zero rather than a blank.

Comment: I interpret the question in the same way. The problem you mention with assuming a value in Column I can be solved by nesting the IF() in another IF().

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing to me.  And your screenshot, which uses different columns than your question, doesn't help.

If what you really want is a formula that will return the last numeric value in column A (eg the first numeric value encountered if you start from the bottom of the column and move upwards), then

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER($A:$A),$A:$A)
```

should do what you want.

[image]

If I have interpreted incorrectly, please try to clarify.